# Override Ansible hosts on a specific role

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have a playbook like below

```
- name: Do something
  hosts: "view-servers"
  roles:
    - { role: role1, var1: "abc" }
    - { role: role2, var2: "def" }
    - { role: role2, var2: "ghi" }
```

The servers in `view-servers` are identical and replicated. So there is no difference from variable point of view except the host name.
On the `role1` above, I need to actually run it just for 1 of the view servers. Something like `view-servers[0]`.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The playbook yaml is actually a **list**, which is why they all start with `- hosts:` (err, or `- name:` in your case, but most don't have named playbooks)

Thus:

```yaml
- hosts: view-servers
  roles:
  - role: role1
- hosts: view-servers[0]
  roles:
  - role: role1
```

And because they are a list, it will run them in the order they exist in the file; so if you want that `view-servers[0]` to run first, move it before the `- hosts: view-servers`, else it'll run them all, and then re-connect to the first one of the group and apply the specified roles to it.

Be forewarned that `view-servers[0]` is highly dependent upon your inventory, so be careful that the 0th item in that group is always the server you intend. If you need more exacting control, you can use a dynamic inventory script, or you can use the [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/add_host_module.html) task to choose, or create, a host and add it to a (new or existing) group as a side-effect of your playbook.